# Middleman Dynamic Pages Issue

Tags: ruby, middleman, static-site

So I have a database called development.sqlite3 and it is in the same directory as my config.rb.

When I go into IRB and type in the following:

```
require 'data_mapper'
DataMapper.setup :default, "sqlite://#{Dir.pwd}/development.sqlite3"

class Post
      include DataMapper::Resource
      property :title,      String
      property :slug_url,   String, :key => true
      property :desc,       String
      property :content,    Text
      property :project,    String
      property :target_url, Text
      property :trackback,  Integer
      property :updated_at, String
      property :created_at, DateTime  # A DateTime, for any date you might like.
end


DataMapper.finalize
DataMapper.auto_upgrade!
posts = Post.all 
puts post.slug_url
```

And this kicks out all the slug_urls like I would expect. Here is what I have at the beginning of of config.rb file.

```
require 'data_mapper'
require 'builder'
require 'maruku'

DataMapper.setup :default, "sqlite://#{Dir.pwd}/development.sqlite3"

class Post
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :title,      String
  property :slug_url,   String, :key => true
  property :desc,       String
  property :content,    Text
  property :project,    String
  property :target_url, Text
  property :trackback,  Integer
  property :updated_at, String
  property :created_at, DateTime  # A DateTime, for any date you might like.
end

DataMapper.finalize
DataMapper.auto_upgrade!

posts = Post.all 

posts.each do |post|
  page "/kw/#{post.slug_url}.haml", :proxy => "/kw/template.haml" do
    @slug_url = post.slug_url
  end
end
```

and my template.haml just has the following in it: `= @slug_url`

When I run `middleman build` I get no errors, and it seems to work fine, but it doesn't create the kw directory or any of the files that it should. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: You should at least create the directory.

Comment: I've changed the .haml to .html and that creates the directory for me in the build folder, obviously it's already created in the source folder. It puts a template.html file in there, but not the files I would expect such as url-slug-something.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, "page" takes output paths, not templates paths in the current version (3.0 beta support both formats).

So you'd want to do something like:

```
page "/kw/#{post.slug_url}.html", :proxy => "/kw/template.html" do
  @slug_url = post.slug_url
end
```

Where you have a `/source/kw/template.html.haml` file for dealing with the data.

Comment: What does the proxy do? When I run this I get a template.html file in the build/kw/ directory that is basically a blank template. To me, that makes it look like its not a middleman issue. Would you agree?

Comment: add `:ignore => true` to avoid outputting the template.html if you don't need it.